# How to check if update Entity (table row) is successful and return true / false response?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Well.. here is the Method:

```
public function likeUnlikeAction($category, $id, $type)
{
    $status = false;
    $message = '';

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Article")->find($id);

    if ($type == 'like') {
        $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() + 1);
    } else {
        $article->setLikes($article->getLikes() - 1);
    }

    $em->persist($article);
    $em->flush();

    $likes = $article->getLikes();

    $response = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message,
        'likes' => $likes
    );

    return new JsonResponse($response);

}
```

How can I check if everything is fine and update `$message` and `$status` When `$em->persist()` and `$em->flush()` returns always null ?

Comment: use `try / catch`

Comment: Hmm.. but if there is a way which doesn't update it, but also doesn't throw error ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm - Basically no.  If an exception is not thrown then you can be certain that the operation succeeded.  And I'd suggest not getting too hung up on trying to catch individual exceptions.  If your code is right then database exceptions should be truly exceptional in most cases and pretty much impossible to recover from.

Comment: @Cerad Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your article and if your getters/setters works you don't have to worrie about `$em->persist()` and `$em->flush()`

You can set your message and status when you don't find the article. Also you can compare the 'likes' number before and after update to see if the update have been applied.

[From symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine.html#updating-an-object) : Notice that calling $em->persist($product) isn't necessary. Recall that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the $product object. In this case, since you fetched the $product object from Doctrine, it's already managed.

Comment: Thanks for the notice about persist :)